# Splitting a file with PowerShell into multiple text files

Tags: powershell

I have to split a file from a unique string to another unique string into multiple text files, but certain parts of the file should not be written to a new file. The file size is 6 MB and contains mostly names and numbers as seen below.

Example of file:

```
WD2GDLPR
Jack        123545
Peter       12564

HR4MJUTL
Mark        4489
Alex        47889

JP3MFRLES
Jane        5632
Toby        48685

1STRHD17-4
Jake        47896
Jess        48896
```

The name of the text file should be the unique string like below.

(How the output should look)

`WD2GDLPR.txt` containing:

```
WD2GDLPR
Jack        123545
Peter       12564
```

`JP3MFRLES.txt` containing:

```
JP3MFRLES
Jane        5632
Toby        48685
```

Current code:

```
    $Path = "C:\Users\Spoderman\Desktop\Testing"
    $InputFile = (Join-Path $Path "bigfile.txt")
    $Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)

    While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
        If ($Line -match "WD2GDLPR") {
          $OutputFile = $matches[1] + "WD2GDLPR.txt"
    }
        If ($Line -match "JP3MFRLES") {
          $OutputFile = $matches[1] + "JP3MFRLES.txt"
    }

    Add-Content (Join-Path $Path $OutputFile) $Line
    }
```

The above code gives me this output but it should look like the first example:
`WD2GDLPR.txt` containing

```
WD2GDLPR
Jack        123545
Peter       12564

HR4MJUTL
Mark        4489
Alex        47889
```

`JP3MFRLES.txt` containing

```
JP3MFRLES
Jane        5632
Toby        48685

1STRHD17-4
Jake        47896
Jess        48896
```

Comment: Please edit the question and use more sensible example data. It's hard to understand what kind of processing is desired. What's more, what should happen to, say, `HR4M` that's in the original data.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Answer (score 0):

I'll help get you started, but you'll need to use what I'm showing and expand upon it. Report back what is and isn't working, and we'll continue on from there.

This one-liner will do several things and can be expanded to finish what you are asking. So here's what's happening:

1. `Get-Content` will read-in the data in the text file and pipe it to `Select-String`.
2. `Select-String` will look for a regex pattern (you can play around with them [here](https://regexr.com/)) and pipe it to a `foreach` loop.
3. `foreach` will loop through each of the matched regex and will pipe it to `New-Item`.
4. `New-Item` will then take that match and create a .txt file.

What I recommend doing is figuring out a way to loop through the data again and grab the lines you need after the regex matches, and then append that data (`Add-Content`) to the correct .txt file. You could always tinker with the one-liner and have it grab that info at the same time as it grabs the regex match. There's various ways to do this. Just think about it logically, write out some pseudo code on what needs to happen, and then start plugging in PowerShell Cmdlets to make it happen.

Here's the PowerShell script to get you going (it's **one line**):

`Get-Content '.\bigdata.txt' | Select-String -Pattern '([A-Z])\w+' | foreach {$_.Matches.Value | New-Item ".\$($_.Matches.Value).txt" -Type File}`

Here's the result of that script:

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcQhd.png)